# L2TP/IPsec VPN Debian/Ubuntu IPsec fails to negotiate or establish security associations

Tags: ubuntu, debian, vpn, ipsec, l2tp

I spent 2 days to configure and figure what's wrong with this setup of L2TP/IPsec VPN. I'm using Debian 8.6 on my VPS server and on my Virtual machine on laptop I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.5. On my VPS im using Strongswan for IKE, xl2tpd and ppp. I have error from Charon called "no shared key found for MY VPS IP ADDRESS - MY IP ADDRESS" which can u see on this logs from journal. Here are files and logs from my Debian, Ubuntu and files content, i don't know what's wrong. I think its small error or something is missing which i can't see here.

**journalctl log** https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg8aT.png

**/etc/ipsec.conf**

```
config setup
    # strictcrlpolicy=yes
    # uniqueids = no

# Add connections here.
conn vpnserver
        type=transport
        authby=secret
        pfs=no
        rekey=no
        keyingtries=1
        left=%any
        leftprotoport=udp/l2tp
        #leftid=@vpn.example.com
        right=%any
        rightprotoport=udp/%any
        auto=add
```

**/etc/ipsec.secrets**

> MY VPS IP ADDRESS %any: PSK "testkeyy1234"

**/etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf**

> [global]
>
> listen-addr =  
>   access control = no 
>   debug avp = yes
>   debug network = yes 
>   debug state = yes
>    debug tunnel = yes
>
> [lns default]
>
> ip range = 192.168.200.100-192.168.200.110
>   local ip = 192.168.200.10
>
> refuse pap = yes 
>   refuse chap = no
>   require authentication = yes
>   name = l2tpd
>   ppp debug = yes
>   pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/xl2tpd-options
>   length bit = yes

**/etc/ipsec.d/l2tp-psk.conf**

> conn L2TP-PSK-NAT
>   rightsubnet=vhost:%priv
>   also=L2TP-PSK-noNAT
>
> conn L2TP-PSK-noNAT
>
> authby=secret
>   pfs=no
>   auto=add
>   keyingtries=3
>     rekey=no
>   dpddelay=10
>   dpdtimeout=90
>   dpdaction=clear
>   ikelifetime=8h
>     keylife=1h
>   type=transport
>   left= GATEWAY IP
>   leftprotoport=17/1701
>
> right=%any
>   rightprotoport=17/%any
>
> conn passthrough-for-non-l2tp
>
> ```
>     type=passthrough
>     left=<MY VPS IP ADDRESS>
>     leftnexthop=<MY VPS GATEWAY ADDRESS>
>     right=0.0.0.0
>     rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
>     auto=route
> ```

**/etc/ppp/xl2tpd-options**

> mru 1280
>   mtu 1280
>   require-mschap-v2
>   auth
>   nodefaultroute
>   lock
>   proxyarp
>   require-chap
>   ms-dns 8.8.8.8
>   ms-dns 8.8.4.4

**/etc/ppp/chap-secrets**

> user      l2tpd   password       *

Here are log from Ubuntu connection info i have Error 300 comunicate

**Linux log** https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T3k3.png

I checked *ipsec verify* command and it gives me no errors. Here is rest of ubuntu files content:

**/etc/ipsec.secrets**

> %any MY VPS IP ADDRESS: PSK "testkeyy1234"

**/etc/ipsec.conf**

> version 2.0
>   config setup
>
> ```
>     plutodebug=none
>     strictcrlpolicy=no
>     nat_traversal=yes
>     interfaces=%defaultroute
>     oe=off
>     protostack=netkey
> ```
>
> conn %default
>
> ```
>     keyingtries=3
>     pfs=no
>     rekey=yes
>     type=transport
>     left=%defaultroute
>     leftprotoport=17/1701
>     rightprotoport=17/1701 conn test      authby=secret
>     right=<MY VPS IP ADDRESS>
>     rightid="<MY VPS IP ADDRESS>"
>     auto=add
> ```

**/etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf**

> [global]
>
> debug avp = no
>   debug network = no
>   debug packet = no
>   debug state = no
>   debug tunnel = no
>
> [lac test]
>   lns = MY VPS IP ADDRESS
>   pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/test.options.xl2tpd
>   length bit = yes
>   redial = no

**/etc/ppp/test.options.xl2tpd**

> plugin passprompt.so
>   ipcp-accept-local
>   ipcp-accept-remote
>   idle 72000
>   ktune
>   noproxyarp
>   asyncmap 0
>   noauth
>   crtscts
>   lock
>   hide-password
>   modem
>   noipx
>
> ipparam L2tpIPsecVpn-test
>   promptprog "/usr/bin/L2tpIPsecVpn"
>
> refuse-eap
>   refuse-pap
>
> remotename ""
>   name "user"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you didn't put a space before the colon in `%any: PSK`. There must be at least one space character on both sides of the colon (unless the colon starts the line), otherwise strongSwan's *stroke* plugin won't be able to load the secret.

Comment: Thank u it worked. I put spaces on server file before IP and after %any now it looks like: (space)IP %any : PSK "password" . On my ubuntu now it looks like: (no space)%any IP : PSK "password". Problem solved.